# With XPath, get a button from a row, that has a cell with a specific text

Tags: html, xpath

I have a rather tricky xpath situation here. I will illustrate it.

Here are my HTML elements:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Click 1<button>
        </td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>DEF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Click 2<button>
        </td>
        <td>MNO</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>Click 3<button>
        </td>
        <td>UVW</td>
        <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, I want to traverse the rows looking for some text (say "PQR"), then select the button of that row.

I have tried this:

```
parent://td[contains(text(), 'PQR')]button
```

But it does not work.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use:

```
//tr[td = 'PQR']/td/button
```

Or, if you want to use contains(), then:

```
//tr[td[contains(.,'PQR')]]/td/button
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and excellent answer! :) I used the version with contains()